# Username case change; awful long time to wait

Tags: support, display-names

(*Understanding that I know I made a boo-boo*)

I've undergone a bit of a re-branding as an independent developer and, after noticing that one can change their username, I figured I would change my StackExchange username to reflect this.

However; in my late-night, code-frenzied haste, I pascal-cased my new name: **BracketWorks** (*when I meant simply to put **Bracketworks***)

I submitted, and immediately noticed. (*post-submission, of course*)

> "Oh well, I'll just fix that."
>           - *last words*

Of course, I recoiled in horror when confronted with a page telling me to wait until early September to do so.

Now, such a limitation makes sense; we can't have people synchronizing their usernames with their social networking status updates.

However what is one to do when faced with such a situation?

Perhaps "change-of-character-case" should be permitted? Alternatively, to whom should I inquire about making such a change preemptively?

(*I understand some may scoff at this concern, but I goofed up and would just like to fix it*)

Comment: I've gone ahead and made the change for you so that you don't have to wait until september. I'll leave the rest of the questions to be answered by the devs.

Answer (score 8):

What you could *try* (and I emphasise try) is change your name on Super User (where I notice it's still your old name) and then on your [accounts tab](https://superuser.com/users/53668/tomcatexodus?tab=accounts) select the

> Copy Super User profile to all Stack Exchange accounts

This used to work but I don't know if they've closed the loop hole. If not what have you lost? Your name on Super User is correct.

You can edit the rest of your profile information later.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisF - Thanks for the suggestion. Zypher has changed the SO profile for me now.

Comment: @BracketWorks - you could still see if works. If it does your profile here should update.

Comment: Yeop @ChrisF - Zypher changed SO, I changed meta, logged into SU and the change propagated. Not 100% on what's happening behind the scenes, but it worked. Thanks again!